# How to pass data from AppDelegate to ViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I'm using Safari to browse a webpage. After I click a button on this page, my Ipad will launch my app. So I implement the method `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url` in the `AppDelegate.m`.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url{
    if (!url) {  return NO; }   
    NSString *URLString = [url absoluteString];
    self.paramArray = [URLString componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];
    NSLog(@"%d",[self.paramArray count]);
    for (int i = 1; i < [self.paramArray count]; i++) {
        NSLog([self.paramArray objectAtIndex:i]);
    }
    return YES;
}
```

The url I used on the webpage was some thing like `myapp://@first_part@second_part@third_part`. `self.paramArray` stores the substrings of url (`myapp://` `first_part` `second_part` `third_part`).

Now I want to show these strings in the textfields in my `ViewController`. How can I pass this NSArray to the `ViewController`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just a few line of code, required to accomplish it.

Put this line in appDelegate.h file

First of all you need to conforms to a protocol as follow

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
```

Now need to declare one property for it to use as follow

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) id<UIApplicationDelegate>delagete;
```

Now the last and final stage to use the property in view controller is as follow

In .h file of viewcontroller
First put reference to appdelegate like this `#import "AppDelegate.h"`
Then one iVar as `AppDelegate *appDel;` in `@interface`

Now in .m file
put `appDel = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];` in view did load method and access the appdelegate's all property there like `appDel.paramArray`.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: can u give me more details plz? like where should I add these lines to?

Comment: does this is ok ? or need some more info ? :)

Comment: I did what u told me. But the `[appDel.paramArray count]` in my `viewDidLoad` method returns `0`. When will the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url` be called?

Comment: does paramArray is one property with (strong, nonatomic) declared in appDelegate.h file?

Comment: After the view is loaded and it is in appear state ie in viewDidAppear methed will be properly suited for this as I think :)

Comment: make sure that the paramArray contains data at the application launch. use NSLog() to conforms that it contains proper data

Comment: oh, `[appDel.paramArray count]` is not `0` anymore if I check it outside the `viewDidLoad` method. So u r right :)

Comment: Thanks buddy :) Glade to know that I am able to help you out.

Comment: Thanks man, hope that I can help others in the future like what u did :))

Comment: Yep It is true that you can in future same as me. some times before I am also same as you. And still looking for help from this site as much more experienced developers are on this site to help us like "new bee" developers, and as you get some experience you also able to help some other who is new to this.