# Passing the values between view controllers in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation

Here's the situation. I have 3 view controllers named as **A**, **B** and **C**.

I'm navigating from **A** to **B** and passing some string , call it as `receivedMember`.

In **B** when I write  `NSLog(@"Name is %@", _receivedMember);`    // it prints the value that was passed from **A**

Then from **B**, I'm navigating to **C** and again returning to **B**. So when I returned to B, I checked the value of `name`. It is `null`.

```
  -(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

     NSLog(@"DID APPEAR %@\n", _receivedMember);   // (null)
    }

    -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
       NSLog(@"WILL APPEAR %@\n", _receivedMember); // (null)
    }
```

**EDIT** Here is the code

**In class A, A ---> B**

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"searchpage"])
    {
        B *cl = segue.destinationViewController;

        cl.receivedMember = strMemberType;

    }
}
```

I'm getting the `strMemberType` from pickerview,

```
-(void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent: (NSInteger)component
{

        strMemberType = [memberTypeArray objectAtIndex:row];

}
```

**In class C, C ---> B**

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"backToSearchSegue"])
    {
        B *cs = segue.destinationViewController;
    }
}
```

**B.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *receivedMember;
```

How can I get the same value when I return to **B** from **C**.? I'm naive in iOS, so please help me out. Is there anyway I can store them in cache file? So that I can access it in any class.

Comment: use singleton or app delegate delegate methods

Comment: Can you please give some links or write the code? I'm naive in iOS.

Comment: once check in class B ,some where you are clearing the data in _name.

Comment: @Sunny No, I'm not clearing anything.

Comment: Or you can use NSUSerDeafults simply... Save value when you are switching from B to C..and Retrive again in C to B's ViewWillAppear

Comment: Show your code and look at other answers - you're probably creating a new instance of B and pushing it... Don't use the app delegate for this stuff @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: you save value as globle NSUserDefault. and use it anywhare.

Comment: @Wain I updated the code, please check once.

Comment: You didn't show how you return from C to B.

Comment: Updated please check @Wain

Comment: `1.`Have you checked that your segue from C->B is being executed? `2.`You aren't setting class B's `name` property in your segue from C->B so it will be nil by default.

Comment: What I need to do? Can you please expound? @RoboticCat

Comment: @DownVoter explain the reason. Title might have mislead you, but take a time to read the entire question before down voting.

Comment: In your A->B segue you have `cl.receivedMember = strMemberType;`. Where is the equivalent code in your C->B segue (`cs.receivedMember = strMemberType`)?

Comment: I'm not using `strMemberType` in `C`. Still I need to do that?

Comment: `backToSearchSegue` should not be a new push segue. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them

Answer (score 2):

in `iOS` the data passing method in used in several ways,

example 1.

AppDelegate

use this link [How to pass data from AppDelegate to ViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677572/how-to-pass-data-from-appdelegate-to-viewcontroller)

example 2:

NSObject class method

use this link [Sending data from one ViewController to another.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18566304/sending-data-from-one-viewcontroller-to-another)

example 3 :

using segue method.

use this link [ios which is the best way to pass data from one viewcontroller to another . through singleton class or *.h file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22961603/ios-which-is-the-best-way-to-pass-data-from-one-viewcontroller-to-another-thro)

example 4 :

singleton class method

use this http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/iOS-5-How-To-Share-Data-Between-View-Controllers-using-a-Singleton

example 5 :

NSUserDefaults

use this link : [Pass data from one ViewController to another ViewController using NSUserdefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24277264/pass-data-from-one-viewcontroller-to-another-viewcontroller-using-nsuserdefaults)

Comment: if u need more assistance , i help with u,

Answer (score 1):

**You will have to use `NSUserDefault` or `Singleton` to handle the values of varaiables accross various Controllers.**

These both are used in such a scenario where you need to maintain and access the variable values across multiple View Controllers. You can opt for either one based on your choice.
`NSUserDefault` can store multiple key-value pairs that are accessible globally throughout the app. Singleton helps you create a object / variable which is static and hence no other instance of it is created afterwards. Only a single instance is retained throughout the app.

The following links might help you.

[Singleton Tutorial](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/)

[Another Singleton Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795997/global-variable-nsmuteablearray-using-singleton-class)

[NSUserDefault Tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-nsuserdefaults--mobile-6039)

[Another NSUserDefault Tutorial](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/quick-tips/storing-data-with-nsuserdefaults/)

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks, I will check out the links and get back to you.

Comment: I have updated the code, can you please have a look?

Answer (score 0):

When you are returning from C to B basically you creating another another instance of B in memory which is not same as what you had when you came from A. Remove sgeue pushviewcontroller on backbutton just type following on backbutton IBAction click.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

It will take you to B which you had when you came from A and and on viewWillAppear your value will remain there

Whenever you push your viewControllers it gets added to self.navigationalController ViewControllers  array.